# Multiple Java applications in Eclipse's Package Explorer or Navigator

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm new to Java and Eclipse, I'm trying to understand the Package Explorer and Navigator. I already imported one Java application in my workspace which I worked on, but now I need to work on a separate (unrelated) Java application, so I imported the second one in Eclipse. But now I see two application folders in Package Explorer and Navigator (two roots).

What should I do to remove the first one from Package Explorer without deleting anything? Do both applications remain in my workspace either way? What should be done when switching applications?

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple unrelated projects in the same workspace. Just give them unique names.

Comment: But I don't want to see the project I'm not working on currently. Should I right-click and Delete? I find that to be an odd thing to be doing if someone wants to see, and work on, one project at a time?